# Pandas replace Na using merge or join

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace Na in column A with based on shared values of column B so column rows with x in column B have 1 in column A and rows with y in column B have 2 in column A

```
A    B   C   D  E
1    x   d   e  q
Na   x   v   s  f 
Na   x   v   e  j
2    y   w   e  v
Na   y   b   d  g
'''
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby.transform('first')`, eventually combined with `convert_dtypes`:

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('first').convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  x  d  e  q
1  1  x  v  s  f
2  1  x  v  e  j
3  2  y  w  e  v
4  2  y  b  d  g
```